# A tricky query - sort of distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with translations (Example is simplified):

The ones having GroupId = 0 are global, the ones having a GroupId > 0 are specific for that group.

```
ID(BitInt), TranslationId(BigInt), GroupId(BigInt), Translation(VarChar(100)
1           1                      0               'Hello'
2           1                      20              'Hi there'
3           1                      25              'Hi'
4           2                      0               'Goodbye'
5           3                      20              'See you'
6           3                      25              'See Ya'
7           4                      25              'Well well'
```

I need to select from this for a specific Group giving me:

If a record exist with the correct GroupId then that one otherwise the global one with GroupId = 0

So lets say I make a query with GroupId = 20
It should return

```
2,1,20,'Hi there'
4,2,0,'Goodbye'
5,3,20,'See you'
```

And a query with GroupId = 25

```
3,1,25,'Hi'
4,2,0,'Goodbye'
6,3,25,'See Ya'
7,4,25,'Well well'
```

And a query with GroupId = 37

```
1,1,0,'Hello'
4,2,0,'Goodbye'
```

Hope this gives some sort of meaning, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just to be sure - GroupId 0 contains all possible records?

Comment: its just a basic where clause:    GroupdID=@testGroup OR GroupID=0

Comment: Actually it is grouped by TranslationId. There can be TranslationId's that are not present with GroupId  0 as 3 and 4 in the example. Some are only present with a single GroupId as 4 in the example. Some again are only present with GroupId 0

Comment: Not a basic where as that will return both the one with GroupId = 0 and the Ones With the specific GroupId.
I need only one of them beeing the Specific if present. Otherwise the one with 0

Comment: Just to point out:
The resultset has to be distinct on TranslationId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (Assuming the combination of `TranslationId` and `GroupId` is unique):

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your next questions)

```
DECLARE @T As TABLE 
(
    ID BigInt, 
    TranslationId BigInt, 
    GroupId BigInt, 
    Translation VarChar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 'Hello'),
(2, 1, 20, 'Hi there'),
(3, 1, 25, 'Hi'),
(4, 2, 0, 'Goodbye'),
(5, 3, 20, 'See you'),
(6, 3, 25, 'See Ya'),
(7, 4, 25, 'Well well')
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @GroupId BigInt = 20

SELECT ID, TranslationId, GroupId, Translation
FROM @T 
WHERE GroupId = @GroupId

UNION ALL

SELECT T1.ID, T1.TranslationId, T1.GroupId, T1.Translation
FROM @T T1
LEFT JOIN @T T2 ON(T1.TranslationId = T2.TranslationId AND T2.GroupId = @GroupId)
WHERE T1.GroupId = 0
AND T2.Id IS NULL
```

Results:

**@GroupId = 20**

```
ID                   TranslationId        GroupId              Translation
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
2                    1                    20                   Hi there
5                    3                    20                   See you
4                    2                    0                    Goodbye
```

**@GroupId = 25**

```
ID                   TranslationId        GroupId              Translation
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
3                    1                    25                   Hi
6                    3                    25                   See Ya
7                    4                    25                   Well well
4                    2                    0                    Goodbye
```

**@GroupId = 37** (not exists in the sample data)

```
ID                   TranslationId        GroupId              Translation
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
1                    1                    0                    Hello
4                    2                    0                    Goodbye
```

Comment: Wow that seems to work...
Sorry for the population stuff, I'm not very often asking SQL questions so just tried to explain in pseudo code where I would have been better of with writing actual Population code :)

Comment: Well, if an answer solved your problem then you should mark it as accepted. Also, keep in mind that it's better to answer questions where you can actually test your answer before publishing it.